# Pass options to AWK script bypassing AWK

Tags: awk, arguments, shebang

Can I get arguments that happen to be AWK options passed directly to a pure AWK script?

Example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f
BEGIN { if (ARGV[1] == "-h") print "whoop" }
```

I want `./myscript -h` to print whoop. But AWK gets the -h first and prints its usage instead.

Running `./myscript -- -h` works but I can't get -- working in the shebang because of the -f.

I know I could use a shell script with AWK in instead.

Comment: I'm not on a Unix that allows the multi argument style `#!` line that you use, so I can't test this: Add `--` at the end of the `#!` line.

Comment: @Kusalananda, that would result in `env -S awk -f -- ./myscript -h`, while what I think they need is `env -S awk -f ./myscript -- -h`. I think that's what the second to last paragraph is trying to say.

Comment: I _think_ that can't be done with just the `#!` line, a shell script sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yeah, that sounds about right.

Comment: @Kusalananda No Unix allows multi argument style `#!`. IIRC FreeBSD used to, but that was long time ago.

Comment: @UncleBilly Sure, but I then noticed that coreutils' `env -S` works even on my OpenBSD machine (which does not allow multiple arguments in `#!`).  It does that because it _simulates_ multiple arguments by splitting the string.  Also, with some light testing, macOS seems to actually support multiple arguments in `#!` without the `env -S` trick.

Comment: If this isn't enough to move you from `I know I could use a shell script with AWK in instead.` to `I know I SHOULD use a shell script with AWK in instead.` let us know as there are plenty of additional examples that'd help demonstrate why you shouldn't use a shebang to call awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of the challenge, it could be done with the FreeBSD [`env`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?env) or with GNU [env](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#g_t_002dS_002f_002d_002dsplit_002dstring-syntax) >= 8.30 (already assumed by the OP) in a shebang:

```
#! /usr/bin/env -S sh -c 'exec awk -f "$0" -- "$@"'
BEGIN { for(i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) print ARGV[i] }
```

```
./myscript -h 1 2 3
-h
1
2
3
```

It doesn't mean that it's a good idea, though.

You could try this, instead:

```
#! /bin/sh
BEGIN { 2>"/dev/null"
        exec awk -f "$0" "--" "$@"
}
BEGIN { for(i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) print ARGV[i] }
```

This assumes that you don't have a `BEGIN` command in your `PATH`.

Comment: FWIW, coreutils 8.26 `env` has no `-S` option.

Comment: My _recommended_ variant works on any POSIX system, even those which do not support shebangs.

Comment: @roaima It was committed on the 21st of April 2018, inspired by FreeBSD (https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/668306ed86c8c79b0af0db8b9c882654ebb66db2)

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU `awk` you can use this

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk --exec
BEGIN { print "==>",ARGV[1],"<==" }
```

Sample use

```
./a -h
 ==> -h <==
```

I haven't tested it, but the `mawk` variant appears to use `-W exec` instead of `--exec`. GNU `gawk` claims to support this too, but it doesn't work with `#!`.

Comment: It _may_ work using the same `env -S` trick the user is already using.